# The constructor File(String) is undefined...how do i remove this error?

Tags: eclipse, excel

How can I fix the `File(String) is undefined` error?

```
int classi(String s) throws BiffException, IOException {
    String[] words = s.split(" ");

    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\feat.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: what should i do to remove this error??

Comment: You should edit your code.

Comment: @Matti the question is implicitly obvious enough. If you don't want to help, just navigate away.

Comment: @OP can you post the full error trace?

Comment: Make sure you are importing `java.io.File` and not some other File.